# Dockercloud-agent installation fails with Depends: sysv-rc (>= 2.88dsf-24) but it is not installable

Tags: docker

I'm trying to install dockercloud-agent on Ubuntu Server 16.10-server-amd64.

I get this error :

```
dockercloud-agent: Depends: sysv-rc (>= 2.88dsf-24) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

When I try to manually install sysv-rc, I get "Package is unavailable... init-system-helpers replaces it". I installed the replacement, but dockercloud-agent installation still needs sysv-rc.

Is there a workaround to this or a better solution?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the dockercloud-agent installer is not up to date with Ubuntu 16.10.

I solved this by **adding the 16.04 repository** `deb http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial main` to my **sources list** `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
echo 'deb http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial main' >> /etc/apt/sources.list
apt-get update
```

Inspired by this comment on GitHub: https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/20698#issuecomment-192606903.